# Azure Search with Azure DocumentDB indexing error: _ts column not present

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

When I create Azure Search index, it failed after I run re-index after editing query.

To reproduce,

1. Create index with `SELECT c.id, c.Text from c`
2. Run index for 500+ data, and Successfully performed.
3. In Azure Portal, edit Azure Search datasource query to 
   `SELECT c.id, c.Text from c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts` in order to make it detect updated data.
4. Run index, and *failed* with below error message.

> The data change detection policy is configured to use column '_ts', but that column is not present in the data source.

I can see `_ts` value exists in Azure DocumentDB at Portal (of course, it is automatically generated by Azure DocumentDB). But what's wrong?

Do I have to delete-and-recreate datasource for `@HighWaterMark`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include _ts in your SELECT clause:

`SELECT c.id, c.Text, c._ts from c WHERE c._ts >= @HighWaterMark ORDER BY c._ts`

Comment: Thanks. it truly works now. It would be good to note at (1) `Data Source > Edit blade` blade, `Query [i]` tooltip, "SELECT <columns>, c_.ts WHERE c._ts > ..." (currently only noted from WHERE clause) or (2) "check SELECT clause includes _ts column" in error message.

Comment: Hi Youngjae, thanks for great feedback. We'll improve this validation error message. I will also email you about your experience with Azure Search. Thanks!